# Turning an Ethercat library into a dll and integrate that dll into labview

Tags: dll, cmake, labview, ethercat

I am trying to convert this https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM library into a dll in order to import it in labview.Can i turn this library into a DLL?And how? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. Please post some of the code you have tried out so far. If you have run into any errors, please feel free to post those as well.

Comment: I just downloaded the library,opened it in Visual Studio but i have no clue as to how i am supposed to generate a DLL from those files

Comment: Did you try building the library? Did it build successfully, or were there some errors? If it built successfully, what libraries were created during the build (`.lib` or `.dll`)? If possible, please add some of this information to your question, to provide more context for where you are at.

Comment: it builds succesfully and i get a .lib as an output but what i need is a .dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to configure CMake to build a `.dll`, instead of a `.lib`, you have to edit the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file from the SOEM repository. Instead of a `STATIC` library, we want a `SHARED` library, so change this:

```
add_library(soem STATIC
  ${SOEM_SOURCES}
  ${OSAL_SOURCES}
  ${OSHW_SOURCES}
  ${OSHW_EXTRA_SOURCES})
```

to this:

```
add_library(soem SHARED
  ${SOEM_SOURCES}
  ${OSAL_SOURCES}
  ${OSHW_SOURCES}
  ${OSHW_EXTRA_SOURCES})
```

Now, re-run `nmake` (which will re-run CMake as well), and a DLL will be built instead.

Comment: Hey,indeed this generates a .dll but i am not really sure it works correctly as labview or a dll viewer cannot see any functions inside this .dll.So i am not sure if it can be used.Thanks for your answers so far!

Comment: fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'soem.lib' also getting this error.